# How to execute jQuery script using asp button?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, button

I just want to ask how to execute a jQuery script using an ASP button? I will be running a VB/C# code first to check the database connectivity. If it fails, I will prompt a jQuery dialog box.

To make it simple, it will run like this:

> Button Clicked > Execute VB/C# command > run jQuery script

I know how to run a dialog box using jQuery from `<button` or `<input` tags but I cannot run both scripts from VB/C# and javascript.

Please help me, 
Ivan

Comment: Yo, if this helps bruv. Learn about page cycles, if you keen I reckon take a look in here: `:)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333455/how-to-call-jquery-from-asp-button Yours question is very open-ended

Comment: The idea is to execute a .NET code first before executing jQuery so you can add .NET conditional statements or whatever you needed. On the link that you provided, it will only run a jQuery using an ASP control. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have a function in JavaScript or jQuery called

```
function runDialog() {
    console.log("Clicked");
    //Add your JQuery dialog code here
}
```

In C#, you then call this function like so

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "runDialog();", true);
```

Hope this helps
Cheers